# Angular Update value in localStorage

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

The problem I'm having, I can't add/change a given item inside a JSON object. I tried to convert it to use a simple `put` but that doesn't work since: `Property "put" does not exist in type of "JSON"`

```
Key: 123 Value:{"name":"123","email":"123","password":"123","country":"123","about":"123","image":""}
```

My method to change the country value.

```
newJson:JSON;
onSubmit(value:any){

            this.newJson = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.id));
            this.newJson.put("country", value.country);
            localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(this.newJson));
    }
```

The value I get from the parameter (the submitted value)

```
{"country":"Portugal"}
```

Comment: can you use this.newJson.country = value.country

Comment: Agreed with @Niladri - once you've parsed the `localStorage`, it's a JS object where you can access its properties using normal dot notation

Comment: also you can declare `newJson:any;`

Comment: Change it to an answer instead of comment and I'll mark it as solution

Answer (score 2):

Try like this :

```
export class Component {
    private jsonObj: any = {};
    private key: string = "123";

    constructor(){
        this.jsonObj = {
            "name": "123",
            "email": "123",
            "password": "123",
            "country": "123",
            "about": "123",
            "image": ""
        }
        localStorage.setItem(this.key, JSON.stringify(this.jsonObj));
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        let localStorageJsonData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.key));
        localStorageJsonData.country = "france";
        localStorage.setItem("obj", JSON.stringify(localStorageJsonData));
        console.log('localStorageJsonData', localStorageJsonData);
    }
}
```